# Why should i use catch by reference when exception pointers are thrown

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, mfc

When catching an exception by reference is the only advantage that i get is avoiding a copy of the exception object being made? Basically the difference between

```
try
{
    CString a_csSQL = _T("SELECT * FROM Library");
    CDatabase aDB;
    aDB.OpenEx(g_csConnectionStringWdDSN,CDatabase::noOdbcDialog));
    aDB.ExecuteSQL(a_csSQL);
}
catch(CDBException *& ex)
{
    ex->Delete();
}
```

AND

```
try
{
    CString a_csSQL = _T("SELECT * FROM Library");
    CDatabase aDB;
    aDB.OpenEx(g_csConnectionStringWdDSN,CDatabase::noOdbcDialog))
    aDB.ExecuteSQL(a_csSQL);
}
catch(CDBException * ex)
{
    ex->Delete();
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown by value and caught by reference, not thrown by pointer. Catching a pointer by reference is pointless (pun). Also in addition to not making a copy (and thereby avoiding slicing), you ensure that no exception is thrown by the exception's copy constructor, which, I agree, would be stupid if it happened, but it's best to ensure your success.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: But doesnt this ensure no slicing in case of a polymorphic exception type is handled?

Comment: A reference would ensure that also.

Comment: [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e5twxsh(v=vs.80).aspx) throws its exceptions by pointer. People who use MFC don't have a choice.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong... isnt it same `CDBException *& ex` as `CDBException ex` as `* &` cancels out each other?

Comment: @sansix I hereby correct you: You are wrong.

Comment: @us2012 yeah now I am also thinking it but can u elaborate?

Comment: @sansix `* &` simply don't cancel each other out here. You were probably thinking of `int a = 5; int b = *(&a);`. In that case, `a` and `b` will both be 5 but that's an entirely different from saying that "`* &` cancel each other out" in general. In particular, in my example `&` takes the address whereas in the case discussed in the question `&` signifies a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the two codes you posted is that the first one catches a *pointer* to an exception by reference, and the second one catches a *pointer* to an exception by value.  In neither case is an exception copied, since you're dealing with pointers.

In general, exceptions should be thrown by value, and caught by reference.  The C++ standard library is designed with this expectation in mind.  However, older libraries, (MFC for instance) throw exceptions by *pointer* as you do here, and are expected to be caught by pointer.

There's no effective difference between catching a *pointer* by value and by reference, except that if you catch by reference that gives you the (completely useless) option of deleting the exception, allocating a new exception with that same pointer, and rethrowing the same exception-pointer.

Comment: In MFC, the option of deleting the exception is not useless, but necessary. MFC exceptions are allocated dynamically with `new` and the catch block that handles them is expected to call the `Delete()` member function to destroy the object.

Comment: @Praetorian: I think you misunderstood what I was saying.  Of course you're expected to `Delete()` it, but catching a pointer by reference also allows you to allocate something else to the same pointer, use `throw;` to throw the same pointer, but pointing at a different exception. (This is, of course, completely useless)

Comment: I apologize, I did misunderstand. Yes, doing that would indeed be useless.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is throw by a pointer you can avoid using reference.

References are really required if the exception is thrown by value.